# Ability to save the data offline and send it when online in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, wiki

In azure we can track the data only if the user connects internet which is online. Suppose user is using the application with out connecting to internet... then how to track the data in offline mode in azure.

Comment: Add more information to your question to get the right help, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of application do you want to develop? If it is a mobile app than there is an option for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync

Comment: For Web Application... Suppose if the user has internet and if he is using the application...each and every action is been tracked and stored in cloud azure....but if user is not having internet access and if they use application iam able to track the users action locally... but how to pass to cloud